# Recode codes into dichotomous ones based on merged vector

Tags: r

I have a dataset where participants gave six open-question answers. These six answers were coded. Some answers can receive more than one code if applicable, and so codes are e.g., 1, 12, 13 (codes separated by commas).

So the dataset looks like

`Answer1 | Code1 | Answer2 | Code2`

etc.

I want to merge all codes given into one vector, to be able to count how many times someone mentioned each code. In total, there were 49 codes available so I would like to end up with 49 variables, each coded based on frequency (e.g., 2 = mentioned twice, 1 = mentioned once, 0 = absent)

So the steps needed are:

1. Merge the code columns all into one, resulting in a vector (e.g., [1 21 9 11 1 4 7 71]
2. Apply some formula to create the 49 variables, with a decision model like "If 1 %in% vector, then variable_1 = +1" If someone mentioned the same thing twice the variable for that person should then result in 2.
3. For each of the 49 variables, I can sum how many times it was mentioned and draft a top 5 of most frequently mentioned categories.

I am not sure where to start here since I am rather new to R. I hope that it is clear what I want to achieve...

EDIT I have already attempted step 1 by using "paste", that resulted in a column with all values next to each other but not sure yet if I can apply a decision rule on that.

```
#Merge all codes from wave 1 into one variable
df$allcodes_w1 <- paste(df$Code_1_1, df$Code_1_2, df$Code_1_3, df$Code_1_4, df$Code_1_5, df$Code_1_6)
```

And removed the commas in case multiple codes were assigned to one answer:

```
df$allcodes_w1 <- gsub(",", "", df$allcodes_w1)
```

I tried this:

```
df$var1 <- ifelse(grepl("1", df$allcodes_w1), 1, 0)
```

But then it also returns 1 if the code is 12 for example. The numbers are still as character btw, should I change to numeric?

Comment: Could you provide a small workable data set that has the essential features of your larger data set? (e.g. one with five rows for two or three answers?) I suspect you can do this with some calls to `pivot_longer()`, `group_by()`, and `summarise()` but I can give a more helpful answer if you give some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Your question says you want to know *how many times each participant mentioned each code*, and the code below answers that question using a slightly different approach from the one you were taking.

I've also had to set up some test data, which may be in a different format from yours. If you provide some sample data I can give a more tailored answer.

The basic approach is to use `pivot_longer()` to put the data into a long format, with one line per code observation per person. Then you can use `group_by()` and `summarise()` to find out how many times each code was mentioned by each person.

```
# load packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# set up test data
  df <- tibble::tribble(
    ~respondent_id, ~answer1, ~code1, ~answer2, ~code2,
    1, "freetext", "12, 34", "freetext", "1, 3, 5, 12",
    2, "freetext", "1, 2, 20", "freetext", "1, 2, 15, 27",
  )

# pivot to a longer format that's easier to work with
df_long <- df %>%
  select(respondent_id, starts_with("code")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("code"), values_to = "codes") %>%
  select(-name)

# get the maximum number of codes in any response, which we'll use below
max_codes <- max(stringr::str_count(df_long$codes, ",")) +1

# separate the column containing all codes into as many columns as needed, then
# pivot even longer, then group_by() and summarise() to find how many times each
# respondent used each code
df_long %>%
  separate(col = "codes", sep = ",", into = paste0("code_", 1:max_codes)) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("code"), as.numeric)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("code"), values_to = "code") %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  group_by(respondent_id, code) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```